# WinSCP File from Mainframe?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, sftp, winscp

I am attempting to use WinSCP.com to pull a file from a mainframe server.

I am able to do this by the DOS FTP command line after logging in:

```
Get 'A.B.C.MYFILE.TXT' \\mytargetpath\test.txt
```

This works and the file is transferred.

However, when I try WinSCP from command line with a file containing:

```
open ftp://name:password@host.com hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 <<key>>"
Get 'A.B.C.MYFILE.TXT' \\mytargetpath\test.txt
exit
```

I get errors such as:

```
Can't get attributes of file ''A.B.C.MYFILE.TXT''.  No such file or directory.
```

I am not sure what is going on here, my assumption was that WinSCP would be using the FTP windows command line client behind the scenes and so the exact same message would work correctly. This is apparently not the case however.

Comment: You're probably in the wrong directory.  You may need to issue a `cd` command.

Comment: Can you include WinSCP log file?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately WinSCP does not support most non-UNIX file systems yet when using FTP mode.

You can browse [this tracker](http://winscp.net/tracker/49) to see how it has progressed so far.

It is not the wrong folder, as mainframe uses different concept of file system, they are called data set(s) instead of file(s). Data set(s) are partitioned, a concept similar to directory/folder but not exactly the same.